# Green lines in Skobbler maps

Tags: android, skmaps

I have a problem with green lines showing up on the map after returning to the Activity with the map.
At first I thought it was because I had the mapview in a Fragment but the problem didn't dissappear after I moved the mapview to the Activity.

Has anybody else experienced this problem and is there a easy solution to it?

[image: Here is a screenshot of the lines]

**EDIT**

When the problem occurs the logcat has multiple lines of:

```
09-30 12:13:58.311  15042-16788/com.example W/Adreno-ES20﹕ <gl_draw_error_checks:575>: GL_INVALID_OPERATION
```

Comment: Which SDK version are you using? (2.2?) Have you upgraded your project from 2.1 to 2.2? Is this reproducing on multiple devices or an a particular hardware/OS version combination?

Comment: @Ando Hi! I was not aware of the version 2.2, I was using 2.1 but upgraded now. I will check if the problem still occurs in the new version.

FYI: The problem was on both of my test devises: Nexus 5 and Sony Xperia Z1, both running Android 4.4

Comment: @Ando Unfortunately this problem persists in version 2.2

Comment: The error seems to indicate that something goes wrong in the OpenGL drawing algorithm. Can you recreate this issue in the demo project?

Comment: @Ando I was able to reproduce it in the demo project. All I had to do was turn on the bicycle lanes: `mapView.getMapSettings().setShowBicycleLanes(true);` It also makes sense since the green lines are the same colors as the bisycle lanes and if the green lines appear then the bisycle lanes dissappear. So it seems to be a bug in the SDK. Are you in the Skobbler team or should I contact them about this?

Comment: I am with the skobbler dev team - thanks for detailed reproduction scenario - I'll file-in a bug report. If you want updates more frequent than what you can get via stackoverflow please also send an email to dev@skobbler.com

Answer (score 0):

More details are needed to reproduce - we've just tested the 2.2 demo project with `setShowBicycleLanes(true);` on multiple devices and it works as expected.

Could you send your modified demo project to dev(at)skobbler.com?

When updating to 2.2, make sure that you also replace the SkMaps.zip archive with the 2.2 one.